# Cannot "Reset this PC"

Tags: windows-10, services, reset

I've recently disabled a whole bunch of services, some of which seem to have been important as I can't even launch taskmgr.exe or anything. I went into settings to reset my PC, but I cannot click the button. Whenever I Open System Restore in Control Panel, the window freezes up.

Update: After about 10 minutes from trying to launch them, I got these:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: I also cannot launch `windows_CEdev.exe`, a program for creating C programs for TI CE calculators. It simply freezes up the Explorer window, and never launches.

Comment: You may have to go to another computer and use the Microsoft Media Creation Tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) to create a bootable USB stick which you can use to install from fresh.

Comment: If you can open a command prompt and remember the names of the services you disabled you might be able to run `net start "service name"` to restart services.

Comment: @Mokubai No. I was trying fix something (I don't remember what), and I was pretty much disabling every service Windows would let me.

Comment: I can open CMD/PowerShell though

Comment: You might be able to get a registry file (`.reg`) for default services from https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/57567-restore-default-services-windows-10-a.html and it might put everything back to default. If it actually runs the reg file properly then you'd do a reboot and hopefully everything will be back to normal.

Comment: See BlackViper's list of services that can be disabled *safely*, http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/ .Once the system is badly mangled, though, restore from your last disk image or do as @Mokubai states, reinstall.